# What does "::" denote in windows netstat results?

Tags: windows, networking, netstat

I'm trying to understand on which interfaces a TCP port is open

Using windows netstat command I get result like :

```
TCP    [::]:10000             MyMachineName:0               LISTENING
```

What does the symbol **"::"** mean here ? for rest of the ports it shows local loop-back or LAN machine name properly or even 0.0.0.0 in some cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's IPv6 to indicate the use of any local address. I.e. equivalent to the IPv4 `0.0.0.0`.

Typically an application would bind to this address when it doesn't mind which interface to use, or to listen on any of the IP interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

In IPv6, :: can be a replacement for multiple fields of zero... Read more here:

http://www.opus1.com/ipv6/whatdoesanaddresslooklike.html